# google script editor mailchimp - fetch segment subscriber

Tags: google-sheets, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm currently trying to fetch mailchimp data for the total amount of subscribers within a predefined auto updating segment within our subscriber list into Google sheets using the script editor. However, I must confess I'm not very knowledgeable in this area and have tried various ways of customizing this code with no luck. I have looked at Mailchimps documentation regarding this but still cannot seem to get this work.

```
function chimpSubscribers() {
var API_KEY = ''; // MailChimp API Key
var LIST_ID = ''; // MailChimp List ID
var SEGMENT_ID =''; //Mailchimp Segment ID

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Subscribers");

var dc = API_KEY.split('-')[1];
var api = 'https://'+ dc +'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0';

  var memberList = '/lists/'+LIST_ID
  var memberSegment = '/segments/'+SEGMENT_ID
    var apiCall = function(endpoint){
    options = {"headers": {"authorization": 'apikey '+API_KEY}};
        apiResponseMembers = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api+endpoint,options);
        json = JSON.parse(apiResponseMembers);
        return json
    }

var members = apiCall ("memberList", "memberSegment");
if (members) {

  var d = new Date();
  var member_count = members.stats.member_count;
  var unsubscribe_count = members.stats.unsubscribe_count;
  var open_rate = members.stats.open_rate;
  var click_rate = members.stats.click_rate;

  var report = [d, member_count, unsubscribe_count, open_rate, click_rate,];

Logger.log(report);

// Clear MailChimp data in Spreadsheet
   sheet.clear();
// Append MailChimp data to Spreadsheet
   sheet.appendRow(["Date", "Total Subscribers", "Unsubscribe Count", "Open Rate", "Click Rate"]);
   sheet.appendRow(report);
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - for anyone else that may need it the code is as follows:

```
function chimpSubscribers() {
var API_KEY = ''; // MailChimp API Key
var LIST_ID = ''; // MailChimp List ID
var SEGMENT_ID = ''; // Mailchimp Segment ID

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Subscribers");

var dc = API_KEY.split('-')[1];
var api = 'https://'+ dc +'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0';

var memberList = '/lists/'+LIST_ID +'/segments/'+ SEGMENT_ID
    options = {"headers": {"authorization": 'apikey '+API_KEY}};
    var apiCall = function(endpoint){
        apiResponseMembers = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api+endpoint,options);
        json = JSON.parse(apiResponseMembers);
        return json
    }

var members = apiCall(memberList);
if (members) {

  var d = new Date();
  var member_count = members.member_count;

  var report = [d,member_count,];

Logger.log(report);

// Clear MailChimp data in Spreadsheet
   sheet.clear();
// Append MailChimp data to Spreadsheet
   sheet.appendRow(["Date", "Total Subscribers"]);
   sheet.appendRow(report);
 }  
}
```